# Excel: Index match if day of date matches?

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have created a time line in excel like this:

Sheet 2

```
A     B      C     D       E

____________________________
01    02     03     04     05
```

I have some data in sheet 1

```
Column A         Column E
01/01/2017       Supplier X
05/01/2017       Supplier B
```

I am wanting to return the name of a supplier using index match where the day (listed on my timeline) matches  the date in column A on sheet 1.

Here's what i'm trying to use but it produces #N/A and # Value errors

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$E:$E,MATCH(F$22,DAY(Sheet1!$A:$A),0))
```

Desired result:

```
A          B      C     D       E

Supplier X_____________________ Supplier B
01         02     03     04     05
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: I recommend that you evaluate the MATCH part on its own before nesting it in INDEX. Presumably you have the day number in F22? Have you tried evaluating it as an array formula?